# Send custom audio response to Google Home for actions-on-google-app and to Alexa with skill-kit-app

Tags: actions-on-google, alexa-skills-kit, google-home

I'm currently building voice-based apps using dialog-flow and Alexa skill kit. Usually, we return the text result from webhook to Alexa or Home, which will read the text result. Now I have a requirement where first I'll generate the audio response(custom speaker voice through my Deep-Learning model) of the text result and wanted to send the generated audio to Home and Alexa to play. I have searched the documentation but saw only support for static audio files .
Is this kind of implementation possible?. How can this be done?

Comment: How exactly do you intend to return an audio response? SSML responses do require the response is an mp3.

Comment: just wanted to know is this the only way possible to send custom audio? Is it possible to send raw audio(as audio stream data).

Comment: That's not something that the platform supports, at least for the Google Assistant.